# What is the entropy of a glass of water?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy

I have some idea what entropy is, but how much is it? It should be a property in $JK^{-1}$, but what is its size? Is it in $10^{15}$, $10^{20}$ or what? For example for a $100ml$ glass of water at $300 K$. How much for a human body?

Comment: Maybe somebody will post a reasonable answer but I suspect our understanding of liquids isn't really there (especially for water). But it should in principle be a calculation one could do - see for instance [the Sackur-Tetrode equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sackur%E2%80%93Tetrode_equation) for the same question about an ideal monatomic gas.

Comment: Determining the entropy of a glass of water by counting the number of micro states may be difficult. However, another way of determining the entropy is from the equation $T dS = dQ$ or $T dS = C(T) dT$, where C(T) is the heat capacity of the glass of water, and integrating from zero temperature up to room temperature.  Unfortunately, it's late and I don't have the energy to do this right now, but it shouldn't be too difficult to get an estimate of the entropy of a glass of water.

Comment: If you are using an ideal gas, you can use  [another approximation I discuss here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/78930).

Answer (score 2):

For a glass of water, a nice and easy approach is to use property tables for saturated water.

**The entropy of water at 300K is 3254.8 J/kg.K** (the value is for a saturated liquid but it is a reasonable estimate for our purpose since the entropy is a strong function of temperature!)

So, for a glass containing **100 ml** of water, entropy is about **325.48 J/K** (assuming density of water is **1g/ml**)