# Entropy density (entropy per particle)

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, entropy, ideal-gas

How I can get this definition for an ideal gas: $s=C v \ln (Pρ^{−\gamma})+ \text{constant} $ ?

- In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/78930) answer it is mentioned that there is a connection with the Sackur-Tetrode relation of the entropy density, but I didn't really get it.
- In [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/116795) answer, there is a mention of that definition but without explanation.

Comment: That isn't what the entropy per particle of the ideal gas is in the first place (see e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ideal_gas#Entropy). That looks kind of like the formula for the _change_ in entropy $\Delta s$ per particle, but still isn't quite right even then.

Comment: That one can be found in Section 83 of Landau's Fluid Dynamics text, but without any explanaition

Comment: Ah, I see. Landau says he discards an "unimportant additive constant", so by $s$ he really means $\Delta s$ from some reference entropy.

Comment: Oh, you're right